# im having a problem at returning a variable on a function

Tags: c#, function

I'm trying to make an encoding tool, but I'm getting an error that I've haven't been able to fix.

I've searched on the the internet but it seems that every error have its conditions.

```
  // ** encode function
  public static void Encode (string Etext) {

  // Code here .

    // returns the value
    return(TEhex); // i think the error is from here .

  }

  // ** decode function
  public static void Decode (string TEdominus2) {


   // code here 

    // returns the value
    return TEddominus; // and here .



  }
```

> Program.cs(19,17): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void'
>   to 'string' [C:\Users\HP\Desktop\ME\Coding & Development\Encoding &
>   Cryptography\Dominos_Algorithm\Dominos_Algorithm.csproj]
>   func.cs(38,5): error CS0127: Since 'func.Encode(string)' returns void,
>   a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression
>   [C:\Users\HP\Desktop\ME\Coding & Development\Encoding &
>   Cryptography\Dominos_Algorithm\Dominos_Algorithm.csproj]
>   func.cs(54,5): error CS0127: Since 'func.Decode(string)' returns void,
>   a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression
>   [C:\Users\HP\Desktop\ME\Coding & Development\Encoding &
>   Cryptography\Dominos_Algorithm\Dominos_Algorithm.csproj]

Comment: If you're returning a value then it needs to be `public static [SomeType] Encode (string Etext)` where[SomeType] is the type returned from the method. Whatever type `TEddominus` is, replace void with that.

Comment: @UK_Dev it gives me an another error ` Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string' `

Comment: @UK_Dev i found it thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to return a value from a `void` method. Change the `void` to the type of the value you want to return. It looks like `Decode` should be:

```
public static string Decode (string TEdominus2)
```

It looks like `Encode` should be string as well, but I can't tell for sure from the code provided.